# Vector function of vectors expansion

Tags: classical-mechanics, vectors, vector-fields

I am reading Landau's [Mechanics](https://archive.org/details/Mechanics3eLandauLifshitz/page/n163/mode/2up). In the solution to the problem 4 on page 138, section 42, it is stated that an arbitrary vector function $\vec f(\vec r,\vec p)$ may be written as $\vec f=\vec r\phi_1+\vec p\phi_2+\vec r\times\vec p\phi_3$, where $\phi_1$, $\phi_2$, $\phi_3$ are scalar functions. Why so?

Comment: It says that an arbitrary vector can be written like that. Probably an arbitrary 3-dimensional vector, from context. I think it is meant to be a vector field. Maybe r and p are in different directions? Otherwise a bit strange thing to state.

Comment: If $r$ and $p$ are linearly independent, then they form a basis together with $r \times p$. In that case you can write every vector as a linear combination of these three. I don't see how the expansion works if they are not independent.

Comment: I think the important part that should be added to this questions is the statement of problem 4: "Show that [f,Mz]=fxn, where f is a vector function of the coordinates and momentum of a particle, an n is a unit vector parallel to the z-axis".  Based on the hints is want you to work thought the Poisson bracket math using the suggested relationships in the rest of the solution.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bl}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}} 
\newcommand{\e}{\bl=}
\newcommand{\p}{\bl+}
\newcommand{\m}{\bl-}
\newcommand{\gr}{\bl>}
\newcommand{\les}{\bl<}
\newcommand{\greq}{\bl\ge}
\newcommand{\leseq}{\bl\le}
\newcommand{\plr}[1]{\left(#1\right)}
\newcommand{\blr}[1]{\left[#1\right]}
\newcommand{\vlr}[1]{\vert#1\vert}
\newcommand{\Vlr}[1]{\Vert#1\Vert}
\newcommand{\lara}[1]{\langle#1\rangle}
\newcommand{\lav}[1]{\langle#1|}
\newcommand{\vra}[1]{|#1\rangle}
\newcommand{\lavra}[2]{\langle#1|#2\rangle}
\newcommand{\lavvra}[3]{\langle#1|\,#2\,|#3\rangle}
\newcommand{\vp}{\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}}
\newcommand{\hp}[1]{\hphantom{#1}} 
\newcommand{\x}{\bl\times}
\newcommand{\qqlraqq}{\qquad\bl{-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!\longrightarrow}\qquad}
\newcommand{\qqLraqq}{\qquad\boldsymbol{\e\!\e\!\e\!\e\!\Longrightarrow}\qquad}
\newcommand{\tl}[1]{\tag{#1}\label{#1}}
\newcommand{\hebl}{\bl{=\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!=}}$

[image]

I think this Figure answers your question. It's up to you to find expressions for $\phi_1,\phi_2,\phi_3$ for given $\mathbf r,\mathbf p,\mathbf f$ with $\mathbf r\x\mathbf p \bl\ne \bl0$.

If
\begin{equation}
\mathbf f \e \phi_1\mathbf r\p\phi_2\mathbf p\p \phi_3\plr{\mathbf r\x\mathbf p}
\tl{01}
\end{equation}
try to prove that
\begin{align}
\phi_1 & \e \dfrac{\plr{\mathbf f\bl\cdot\mathbf r}\Vlr{\mathbf p}^2\m\plr{\mathbf f\bl\cdot\mathbf p}\plr{\mathbf r\bl\cdot\mathbf p}}{\Vlr{\mathbf r\x\mathbf p}^2}
\tl{02.1}\\
\phi_2 & \e \dfrac{\plr{\mathbf f\bl\cdot\mathbf p}\Vlr{\mathbf r}^2\m\plr{\mathbf f\bl\cdot\mathbf r}\plr{\mathbf r\bl\cdot\mathbf p}}{\Vlr{\mathbf r\x\mathbf p}^2}
\tl{02.2}\\
\phi_3 & \e \dfrac{\mathbf f\bl\cdot\plr{\mathbf r\x\mathbf p}}{\Vlr{\mathbf r\x\mathbf p}^2}
\tl{02.3}
\end{align}

Note that
\begin{equation}
\Vlr{\mathbf r\x\mathbf p}^2\e \Vlr{\mathbf r}^2\Vlr{\mathbf p}^2\m\plr{\mathbf r\bl\cdot\mathbf p}^2\e \Vlr{\mathbf r}^2\Vlr{\mathbf p}^2\sin^2\theta
\tl{03}
\end{equation}

Comment: What if I take $\vec f(\vec r,0)=(r_x^2,r_y^2,r_z^2)=\vec r\phi_1$ , it seems to fail.

Comment: What is this equation ??? I has no sense. Look at the vector $\mathbf f$ as any arbitrary 3-vector.

Comment: But $\vec f$ is an arbitrary vector function.

Comment: I think you spent more time writing all those newcommands than you saved using them.

Comment: @Kyle Kanos : Thanks for your attention. I have the set of these ''newcommands'' in a text file and I copy-paste it in my posts in nanoseconds, so reducing the time I spend in the main body of the posts especially in cases of very long length.

Comment: I think you overstate your copy+paste efficacy.

Answer (score 0):

take  arbitrary vector in 3D space

$$\vec R=c_1\hat g_1+c_2\hat g_2+c_3\hat g_3\tag 1$$

where $~\hat g_i~$ are the independent  basis vectors, and  $~c_i~$ are the scalar components of the vector R.

now your case

$$\vec f=\phi_1\,r\,\hat r+\phi_2\,p\,\hat p+\phi_3\,|r\times p|\,\hat{r}_p\\
r_p=\vec r\times \vec p$$

comparing with equation (1)

$$c_1=\phi_1\,r\,,\hat g_1=\hat r\\
c_2=\phi_2\,p\,,\hat g_2=\hat p\\
c_3=\phi_3\,|r\times p|\,,\hat g_3=\hat r_p$$

thus there is noting unusual in this vector description

remarks:

the basis vectors must not be perpendicular to each other  $~\vec r\cdot\vec p\ne 0$

Comment: do you mean the basis vectors must not be parallel to each other?

Comment: I mean they can be skew ? to each other $~\vec r\cdot\vec p\ne 0$